# Почему куки не сохраняются?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, express, cookie

На клиенте не сохраняются куки отправленые Express.
После успешной авторизации кук нету
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Браузер говорит что нужно изменить SameSite, но в любом случае оно блокирует, кроме SameSite=None + secure=true, но т.к это режим development используется http протокол
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Server
server.js

```
app.use(cors({'credentials': true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}))
app.use(cookieParser())
```

auth.controller.js(login)

```
async login(req, res) {
        try {
            //Находим пользователя, получаем jwt
            res.status(202).cookie('jwt', jwt, {
                         sameSite: 'strict',
                         maxAge: 90*24*60*60,
                         httpOnly: true,
            }
)
            res.json({jwt, user})
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(400).json({message: 'Login error'})
        }        
    }
```

Front login

```
export const signIn = (objectLogin) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
          const res = await axios.post(`${host}/auth/login`, {objectLogin}, {withCredentials:true})
          dispatch(setUser(res.data.user))
    }
    
}
```

Comment: А они точно приходят?

Comment: А ещё стоит `Path: '/'` указать

Comment: @AlexeyTen указал, не помголо. Бек их точно отпраляет, так как тестил через Постмен(там появляются куки). А как проверить что они приходят на фронт? В хедерах нет инфы про куки

Comment: Посмотреть на владке Network что приходит

Comment: @AlexeyTen в Response Headers есть Set-Cookie. Но почему они не устанавливаются в Cookies Storage?

Comment: Покажите как браузер видит ответ сервера. В частности заголовок `Set-Cookie`

Comment: @AlexeyTen добавил инфу и фото в вопрос

Comment: Сохранять такую куку будет небезопасно - любой сайт сможет слать запросы в ваш express и творить всякие гадости (и нет, Access-Control-Allow-Origin здесь не поможет), если вы не сделаете защиту от CSRF. Лучше откажитесь от кук и поместите jwt в какой-нибудь localStorage

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое, а можно какую-то статью или т.п на эту тему?

Comment: Тут скорее вопрос зачем у вас сайт и апи на разных доменах?

Comment: @AlexeyTen все на локал хосте, просто разные порты

Comment: Это и есть «разные домены». Запустите на одном. У вас же в реальном сайте будет один домен, правда?

Comment: @AlexeyTen не до конца вас  понял. А как можно запустить на одном домене во время разработки? Просто у меня фронт на 3000 порте, а апишка на 8000

Comment: Проксировать одно через другое. Или поставить перед ними веь-сервер (nginx и т.п.)

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, почитаю